# Comparar um campo de uma tabela com outra tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando criar uma consulta no SQL Server para saber se a cidade que foi preenchida no momento do cadastro que a pessoa fez, está igual a um campo de cidade de outra tabela que já possui todos os municípios do Brasil, como posso fazer isso?

[image: Tabela de Municípios]

[image: Tabela de Pessoas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não achei muito claro a pergunta, mas entendi o que você quer fazer, como faltam algumas informações acredito que você queira comparar as informações da tabela. Para isto existe um comando chamado `EXISTS`

```
SELECT CIDADE FROM PESSOA P
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM GMUNICIPIO WHERE P.CIDADE = GMUNICIPIO.NOMEMUNICIPIO)
```

> Quando uma subconsulta é apresentada com a palavra-chave EXISTS, a
>   subconsulta funciona como um teste de existência. A cláusula WHERE da
>   consulta externa testa se as linhas retornadas pela subconsulta
>   existem. A subconsulta não produz de fato nenhum dado; ela retorna um
>   valor TRUE ou FALSE.

Verifique : https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189259(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Show de bola Lucas, mt obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Seria um boa se vc colocasse a tabela junto da sua pergunta (Uma imagem com a estrutura da tabela, por exemplo).

Mas bem eu li sua pergunta e se eu entendi o que vc quer, vc vai digitar um valor em um campo e vc quer saber se o que foi digitado está na tabela de municipios... (Seria uma boa vc explicar se essa busca vai ser feita com valores parecidos ou valores exatamente iguais também). Vou colocar dois exemplos e veja se algum da certo...

```
SELECT nome_cidade FROM GMUNICIPIOS WHERE nome_cidade LIKE '%nome_digitado%';
```

Esse primeiro exemplo vai trazer todos os resultados de textos parecidos com o que foi digitado. por exemplo, se o usuario digitar 'São' vai trazer São paulo, São vicente, São Caetano..

```
SELECT nome_cidade FROM GMUNICIPIOS WHERE nome_cidade = 'nome_digitado'
```

Esse segundo exemplo tras apenas o que for igual. Por exemplo, se o usuario digitar 'São' não vem nada de resultado, mas se digitar 'São paulo', vai vir a cidade de São paulo apenas.

Apenas lembrando que o texto 'nome_digitado' é apenas uma referencia e cabe a você trocar essa referencia pelo que o usuario digitar

Comment: Boa abordagem tambem :) +1

Comment: Editei a pergunta, acho que ficou mais claro o que preciso, obrigado pela ajuda Matheus

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria dessa forma, se o count for maior que zero o municipio existe no seu DB.
Estou supondo que sua tabela possui o Campo `Municipio` e `Id`, ai voce adapta para a sua necessidade!

```
declare @municipio varchar(50)
set @municipio = 'Santos'

declare @Count int

set @count = (select count(Id) from GMUNICIPIO where Municipio = @municipio)
```

Comment: Thiago, editei a pergunta, acho que agora ficou um pouco mais claro o que quis dizer, será que consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Entendi a pergunta, a abordagem que eu postei é diretamente no SQL, no meu exemplo o @municipio sera o input do usuário, portanto no SQL estou comparando o que o usuário digitou com o que você tem no DB.
Posta aqui também a estrutura da sua tabela por favor.

Comment: Thiago, coloquei print das tabelas, se você reparar, na tabela de municípios as cidades são cadastradas somente com a primeira letra maiúscula, mas quando a pessoa vai fazer o cadastro, o campo é livre, logo, ela preenche da maneira que ela quiser, daí quero comparar o campo cidade da tabela de pessoa com o campo "nomemunicípio", se tiver diferente, irei corrigir.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Marcilio, minha sugestão seria utilizar um join simples:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN GMUNICIPIO.CODMUNICIPIO IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS EXISTE, PPESSOA.NOME FROM PPESSOA LEFT JOIN GMUNICIPIO ON PPESSOA.CIDADE =  GMUNICIPIO.NOMEMUNICIPIO
```

Com a consulta acima vc ira visualizar as pessoas que tem o cadastro coincidindo com a tabela municipio através da coluna [EXISTE] e seu respectivo nome através da coluna [NOME]